# How do I run this on my local server 30000? rails s is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, terminal, version-control, rubygems

This is what I get when I type `rails s`. I've updated bundle, gems, rails everything I can possibly think of. How do I run this on local host 3000?

```
=> Rails 5.1.7 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
    66: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    65: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    64: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    62: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    61: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    60: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    59: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    58: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    57: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    56: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    55: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    54: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    53: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    52: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    51: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    50: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    49: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    48: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    47: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    46: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    45: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    42: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    40: from /Users/kevinchoi/projects/resources/misc/teachpulse/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    37: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    36: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    35: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    34: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    33: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    32: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    31: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    30: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    29: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `on_load'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `each'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in `block in on_load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `establish_connection'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 0x0009): dependent dylib '/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib' not found for '/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/11.1/lib/libpq.5.11.dylib' - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle (LoadError)
    66: from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
    65: from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    64: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    63: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
    62: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
    61: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    60: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    59: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    58: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `perform'
    57: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:130:in `tap'
    56: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `block in perform'
    55: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:42:in `start'
    54: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:80:in `log_to_stdout'
    53: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    52: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:24:in `app'
    51: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    50: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    49: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    48: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    47: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    46: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    45: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    44: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    43: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    42: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    41: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    40: from /Users/kevinchoi/projects/resources/misc/teachpulse/config/environment.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    39: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/application.rb:353:in `initialize!'
    38: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:58:in `run_initializers'
    37: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    36: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    35: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    34: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    33: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    32: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    31: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    30: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    29: from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    28: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:59:in `block in run_initializers'
    27: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    26: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-5.1.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    25: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    24: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `on_load'
    23: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:40:in `each'
    22: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:41:in `block in on_load'
    21: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:65:in `execute_hook'
    20: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:60:in `with_execution_control'
    19: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    18: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `instance_eval'
    17: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:124:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    16: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:58:in `establish_connection'
    15: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:882:in `establish_connection'
    14: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:186:in `spec'
    13: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    12: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    11: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    10: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     9: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activerecord-5.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
     8: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     7: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
     5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
     3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
     2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
     1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.7/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
```

Comment: All up to date I think. What do you mean by that question?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: PostgresSQL....

Answer (score 0):

The last line of the logs:
`Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)`

[Here](https://gist.github.com/jwo/4512764#file-postgres-database-yml) for PostgreSQL. you can checkout a sample database.yml config file, or if you are using another adapter, add the gem to your `Gemfile`